# dotnetnuke event module other modules disappear

Tags: dotnetnuke

ok i have a dotnetnuke default event module installed in the website . it is at the bottom of the page in a eventcontentpane i designed for it on the home page. the thing  is that when i click on any event on the calender it displays the event details in the middlecontentpane on the page but everything (other modules) disappears .what could be the work around ? anything guys? or i have to create a new detail module for that

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of the Events module, you should see an option in settings for "Event Detail New Page:". If that is unchecked, it should do what you are wanting.

If you don't have that option, make sure you've got the latest version of the module.